# $ionicHistory does not work with ion-tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation, ionic-framework

I'm having problems using [`$ionicHistory`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) on pages where `ion-tabs` are used. I use this to navigate to the previous view (using `goBack()`). When I put tabs in a view, the history is wrong, back view is two views before.

To demonstrate this I have create a demo app (plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wS4G82N4WL7EJUgehDMu)) that has 4 pages/views. Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 4. The last page has tabs on it.

```
angular
.module("demoapp", ['ionic'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
           url: '/',
           controller: 'firstController',
           templateUrl: 'first.html',
        })
        .state('second', {
           url: '/second',
           controller: 'secondController',
           templateUrl: 'second.html',
        })
        .state('third', {
           url: '/third',
           controller: 'thirdController',
           templateUrl: 'third.html',
        })
        .state('fourth', {
           url: '/fourth',
           controller: 'fourthController',
           templateUrl: 'fourth.html',
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  }])
.factory("historyFactory", ['$ionicHistory', function($ionicHistory){
  var show = function() {
    var text = "";

    var vh = $ionicHistory.viewHistory();
    if(vh !== null) {
      text += "VIEWS=" + JSON.stringify(vh.views);
      text += "BACK=" + JSON.stringify(vh.backView);
    }

    return text;
  }

  return {
    show : show,
  }
}])
.controller("firstController", [
  '$scope',
  '$location', 
  function($scope, $location){
  $scope.next = function() {
    $location.path("/second");
  };
}])
.controller("secondController", [
  '$scope',
  '$location', 
  '$ionicHistory',
  'historyFactory', 
  function($scope, $location, $ionicHistory, historyFactory){
    $scope.next = function() {
      $location.path("/third");
    };

    $scope.prev = function() {
      $ionicHistory.goBack();
    };

    var init = function() {
      $scope.data = historyFactory.show();
    };

    init();
}])
.controller("thirdController", [
  '$scope',
  '$location', 
  '$ionicHistory', 
  'historyFactory', 
  function($scope, $location, $ionicHistory, historyFactory){
    $scope.next = function() {
      $location.path("/fourth");
    };

    $scope.prev = function() {
      $ionicHistory.goBack();
    };

    var init = function() {
      $scope.data = historyFactory.show();
    };

    init();
}])
.controller("fourthController", [
  '$scope',
  '$ionicHistory', 
  'historyFactory', 
  function($scope, $ionicHistory, historyFactory){
    $scope.prev = function() {
      $ionicHistory.goBack();
    };

    var init = function() {
      $scope.data = historyFactory.show();
    };

    init();
}]);
```

This is how the view with tabs looks like:

```
<ion-view>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced">
    <ion-tab title="Tab One">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-arrow-back" ng-click="prev()"></button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Page 4 - Tab 1</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="has-header">
          <h3>History</h3>
          <p>{{data}}</p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>    
  </ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

On the second page, the view history looks like this:

```
VIEWS=
{"002":{"viewId":"002","index":0,"historyId":"root","backViewId":null,"forwardViewId":"003","stateId":"first","stateName":"first","url":"/"},
 "003":{"viewId":"003","index":1,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"002","forwardViewId":null,"stateId":"second","stateName":"second","url":"/second"}}
BACK=
{"viewId":"002","index":0,"historyId":"root","backViewId":null,"forwardViewId":"003","stateId":"first","stateName":"first","url":"/"}
```

On the third page, one more view is added:

```
VIEWS=
{"002":{"viewId":"002","index":0,"historyId":"root","backViewId":null,"forwardViewId":"003","stateId":"first","stateName":"first","url":"/"},
 "003":{"viewId":"003","index":1,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"002","forwardViewId":"004","stateId":"second","stateName":"second","url":"/second"},
 "004":{"viewId":"004","index":2,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"003","forwardViewId":null,"stateId":"third","stateName":"third","url":"/third"}}
BACK=
{"viewId":"003","index":1,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"002","forwardViewId":"004","stateId":"second","stateName":"second","url":"/second"}
```

But on the fourth page, with the `ion-tabs` the view history remains the same.

```
VIEWS=
{"002":{"viewId":"002","index":0,"historyId":"root","backViewId":null,"forwardViewId":"003","stateId":"first","stateName":"first","url":"/"},
 "003":{"viewId":"003","index":1,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"002","forwardViewId":"004","stateId":"second","stateName":"second","url":"/second"},
 "004":{"viewId":"004","index":2,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"003","forwardViewId":null,"stateId":"third","stateName":"third","url":"/third"}}
BACK=
{"viewId":"003","index":1,"historyId":"root","backViewId":"002","forwardViewId":"004","stateId":"second","stateName":"second","url":"/second"}
```

Is this a bug with `$ionicHistory` when using `ion-tabs` or am I doing something wrong in the tabs view?

Comment: I have more or less the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004332/ionic-tabs-and-side-menu-history. Have you tried to place fourth state inside third? `.state('third.fourth') {...` and to navigate there '/third/fourth'

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap ion-tabs to avoid this problem

```
<ion-view>

  <div>
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced">
    <ion-tab title="Tab One">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-arrow-back" ng-click="prev()"></button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Page 4 - Tab 1</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="has-header">
          <h3>History</h3>
          <p>{{data}}</p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Tab Two">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-arrow-back" ng-click="prev()"></button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Page 4 - Tab 2</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="has-header">
          <p>Content of tab 2.</p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
  </div>

</ion-view>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pVDu9e7QZHzMt3A154i7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The `ion-tabs` introduce parallel stacks to maintain history of each tab and so the `$ionicHistory.goBack` changes the history state in the current stack. You can solve your issue by removing the tab or adding tabs to all views. There is an excellent explanation for this in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385026/3878940

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding an empty ion-view above ion-tabs at the very top of the page.

I guess this 'tricked' the $ionicHistory into believing that my page was rendering a regular view rather than a tabbed view.