# $ionicHistory.backView has incorrect state when go to previous state manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I did a small experiment: http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/NqMomm?editors=101

Here is my state flow (click on the buttons): `Home -> Fact1 -> Fact2 -> Fact3 -> Fact2`

On each state change, I am showing in `console.log` for `$ionicHistory.backView` 
However, you can see in `pen.js:64` line, weird things happen. The `$ionicHistory.backView` "thinks" that I got to `app.fact2` from a back button, and it shows `app.fact1` as the previous state (line `pen.js:53`). This is incorrect, right? It should show `app.fact3` as the previous state because I got to `app.fact2` state **MANUALLY** by clicking the button. I also showed the value from `$timeout` (line `pen.js:59`) just in case it's slow. But it's still incorrect.

```
pen.js:56 stateChangeSuccess
pen.js:64 State change from: tabs.home to: tabs.fact1
pen.js:52 $scope.$watch $ionicHistory.backView change detect. newVal:
pen.js:53 tabs.home
pen.js:58 $timeout after 2 sec $ionicHistory.backView().stateName
pen.js:59 tabs.home
pen.js:56 stateChangeSuccess
pen.js:64 State change from: tabs.fact1 to: tabs.fact2
pen.js:52 $scope.$watch $ionicHistory.backView change detect. newVal:
pen.js:53 tabs.fact1
pen.js:58 $timeout after 2 sec $ionicHistory.backView().stateName
pen.js:59 tabs.fact1
pen.js:56 stateChangeSuccess
pen.js:64 State change from: tabs.fact2 to: tabs.fact3
pen.js:52 $scope.$watch $ionicHistory.backView change detect. newVal:
pen.js:53 tabs.fact2
pen.js:58 $timeout after 2 sec $ionicHistory.backView().stateName
pen.js:59 tabs.fact2
pen.js:56 stateChangeSuccess
pen.js:64 State change from: tabs.fact3 to: tabs.fact2
pen.js:52 $scope.$watch $ionicHistory.backView change detect. newVal:
pen.js:53 tabs.fact1
pen.js:58 $timeout after 2 sec $ionicHistory.backView().stateName
pen.js:59 tabs.fact1
```

**QUESTION**

1. How to correct this behavior? Maybe rewrite this delegate or override it somehow?
2. Is there a workaround? As I rely on the correct **previous state** in order to show/hide something.

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
      controller: "MainCtrl"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact1', {
      url: "/fact1",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact1.html",
          controller: 'Fact1TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact2', {
      url: "/fact2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact2.html",
          controller: 'Fact2TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact3', {
      url: "/fact3",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact3.html",
          controller: 'Fact3TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $ionicHistory.backView() ? $ionicHistory.backView().stateName : null;
  }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('$scope.$watch $ionicHistory.backView change detect. newVal:');
    console.log(newVal);
  });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    console.log('stateChangeSuccess');

    $timeout(function(){ 
      console.log('$timeout after 2 sec $ionicHistory.backView().stateName');
      console.log($ionicHistory.backView().stateName);
    }, 2000);
    });
})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  // console.log('Home');

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    console.log('State change from: ' + fromState.name + ' to: ' + toState.name);
  });
})

.controller('Fact1TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  // console.log('Fact1');
})

.controller('Fact2TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  // console.log('Fact2');
})

.controller('Fact3TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  // console.log('Fact3');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Navigation Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact1.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact1">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact2">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact3.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact3">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sometimes this happen when some error occures before back button pressed

Comment: That's vague. What's error? I have no error in the console as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of questions about history and navigation among the issues open on github.

I guess the navigation is broken and needs to be fixed.

`$ionicHistory` keeps track of the view pushing each visited view on a stack. 
Actually there are 2 arrays there:

```
$ionicHistory.viewHistory().views
```

and

```
$ionicHistory.viewHistory().histories
```

I guess the first one is the history of views for the current stack while the second considers all the histories.
Different navigations can have different histories: tabs, sidemenu etc etc, and Ionic should remember each state when you switch from one history to the other.

Reading through their [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) you can find this:

> Unlike a traditional browser environment, apps and webapps have
>   parallel independent histories, such as with tabs. Should a user
>   navigate few pages deep on one tab, and then switch to a new tab and
>   back, the back button relates not to the previous tab, but to the
>   previous pages visited within that tab.

You can find the **currentHistoryId** here: `$ionicHistory.currentHistoryId()`.

I've changed your example a little bit displaying the 2 arrays when entering the view of the main controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $ionicHistory) {
      $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
        var history = $ionicHistory.viewHistory();
        angular.forEach(history.views, function(view, index){
            console.log('views: ' + view.stateName);
        });
        angular.forEach(history.histories[$ionicHistory.currentHistoryId()].stack, function(view, index){
            console.log('history stack:' + view.stateName);
        });
    });
})
```

As you can see, the first array **views** keeps track of all the views you have visited.
If you go back and forth in doesn't add elements if you are displaying a view you've previously visited.

Each view has two properties: **backViewId** and **forwardViewId**. These 2 values seems to be part of the view when the elements are added to the collection. They don't change when you navigate.

So, what happens is when you follow the sequence:

```
Home -> Fact1 -> Fact2 -> Fact3 -> Fact2
```

Ionic finds the view `Fact2` in the collection, gets it's `backViewId` (which points to `Fact1`) and that's what it will use as a view to go back to.

I didn't some debugging in the code and tried to force the back-view myself but things get messed up.

I guess they've chosen this path cause when you're back to the root - home - the back button should be hidden.
Things don't work as expected when you follow the sequence:

Another thing I've noticed is the fact that sometimes views are added to this collection even if the element is already there.

You can try the sequence:

```
Home -> Fact1 -> Fact2 - Home (button)
```

As you can see now the back button (in the header) tells you the back view is Fact2 and in fact the console shows the same:

- views: tabs.home
- views: tabs.fact1
- views: tabs.fact2
- views: tabs.home
- history stack:tabs.home
- history stack:tabs.fact1
- history stack:tabs.fact2
- history stack:tabs.home

For some strange reason this time a new view has been added to the collection and the regular pattern has changed.

There's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kpepwx?editors=101) here with some tests.

Comment: I am thinking to submit this as a bug but just want to ask and confirm since I can't find anything related to this by searching $ionicHistory. I think the workaround is to handle state navigation via Back button differently from state.go

Comment: Can you send me the issue link?

Answer (score 0):

My solution/workaround:

Create an additional state to traverse to that references the same url, templateUrl, and controller.

For example if I have:

`$stateProvider.state('fact2', {
    url: '/fact2/:factFilter',
    templateUrl: 'fact2.html',
    controller: 'Fact2Ctrl'
  })`

Then I also create a "fact2" duplicate with only a different state name

`$stateProvider.state('fact2_duplicate', {
    url: '/fact2/:factFilter',
    templateUrl: 'fact2.html',
    controller: 'Fact2Ctrl'
  })`

If I am receiving the funny transition behavior, I can call `$state.go('fact2_duplicate')` and the history will be more inline to what I am expecting.

Hope this helps someone.