# Controller executing twice with ui-router nested states (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

## Problem

My Ionic app lets you choose a Project from the side menu, and then displays two tabs (Tasks, Messages) in the main content area. The tasks and messages tabs are nested states of project.

When you change projects in the side menu, **`TaskListCtrl` gets executed twice.** See the [live demo](http://ionic-projects-demo.kylefox.ca/#/home) and watch the console as you change between projects. I also have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHVsMGhu42M) which shows the issue in detail.

How do I stop `TaskListCtrl` from executing twice? Is there a better way I could be structuring these nested states?

## Code

*Full code is on [GitHub »](https://github.com/kylefox/ionic-projects-demo/tree/master/www)*

Here's my `$stateProvider` config:

```
.state('project', {
  url: "/projects/:projectID",
  abstract: true,
  cache: false,
  controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
  templateUrl: "templates/project.tabs.html",
  resolve: {
    project: function($stateParams, Projects) {
      return Projects.get($stateParams.projectID);
    }
  }
})

.state('project.tasks', {
  url: '/tasks',
  views: {
    'tasks-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/task.list.html',
      controller: 'TaskListCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And the relevant snippet from `controllers.js`:

```
.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function($scope, project) {
  $scope.project = project;
  console.log('=> ProjectDetailCtrl (' + $scope.project.name + ')')
})

.controller('TaskListCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.tasks = $scope.project.tasks;

  console.log('\t=> TaskListCtrl')
  console.log('\t\t=> $stateParams: ', $stateParams)
  console.log('\t\t=> $scope.tasks[0].title: ', $scope.tasks[0].title)
})
```

## Resources

- [Live demo](http://ionic-projects-demo.kylefox.ca/) (watch the console logs as you change between projects)
- [Video showing the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHVsMGhu42M)
- [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/kylefox/ionic-projects-demo/tree/master/www)

## Notes

- I am aware there are similar questions on StackOverflow — however, none of the solutions they offer solved my issue.*
- I've read this can happen when attaching the controller both in `$stateProvider` and with `ng-controller` — however, I've checked and **I'm not doing this.** I'm only attaching the controller with `$stateProvider`.

Comment: I don't have any advice other than do a deep debug session and make sure your tab isn't being called twice. I've been bitten by routing and angular tabs working oddly before. Essentially what happens is that the tabs will change state all the way through to the final tab and then bounce back to the first one. This may not be your problem but since you've exhausted almost every other avenue  it might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks — it's reassuring to know I'm not overlooking something simple. I'll dig into the tabs more and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [tuckerjt07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270615/tuckerjt07) is right.

It seems to be an issue with routing and parameters and ionic tabs.
I've spend almost the whole day trying to figure out what is going on.

I thought the problem was with the fact you're using an abstract controller with parameters, but that's not the problem.

I've checked if the side menu was interfering with tabs but, again, the problem is not there.

I've checked the scope trying to eliminate friction using `controllerAs` and avoiding to reference the $scope object to store the viewmodel but ... nothing.

I've created a simplified version of your application [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3al3x1OVlZ1qXabWz36H?p=info).
There's not much in there and the navigation is through constants in the header. 
As you can see the problem is still there.

Doing a little bit of debugging it seems that the problem sits [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/6c9bc15b2996ae9183624c84a2709fd33f80d20b/js/angular/controller/navViewController.js#L269).
That line calls the controller twice. You can check it yourself adding a breakpoint at line 48435 in **ionic.bundle.js**.

The only option you have is to change your **project.tabs.html** and load the list of tasks without the sub-view. Something like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ project.name }}: Tasks">

<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

  <ion-tab title="{{ project.name }} Tasks" icon="ion-home">

    <ion-nav-view>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat='task in project.tasks'>
            {{ task.title }}
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-nav-view>

  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" ui-sref="tabs.tab2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tabs-tab2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Another" icon="ion-help-buoy" ui-sref="tabs.tab3">
    <ion-nav-view name="tabs-tab3"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

You can check how it works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z7pDM4aBqmDOTZ3JqpTS?p=info).

I guess we should open an issue.

Comment: Thanks for digging so deeply and opening the issue. As an Ionic newb it would've taken me forever to go this deep. Note: issue is on GitHub https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4089

Comment: @KyleFox: Glad I've helped, in a way. I had answered a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364578/ionichistory-backview-has-incorrect-state-when-go-to-previous-state-manually) few days back. It seems that lot of people are finding it difficult to work with navigation/subnavigation and history. Hopefully someone will manage to fix that. Cheers.