# Ionic different tab content

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to do a hybrid app using ionic with the structure that look like this:

```
#/app                 (sidemenu.html)
#/app/noTabContent1   (notab-content1.html)
#/app/noTabContent2   (notab-content2.html)
#/app/tab1            (tab1.html)
#/app/tab1/content1   (tab1-content1.html)
#/app/tab1/content2   (tab1-content2.html)
#/app/tab2            (tab2.html)
#/app/tab2/content1   (tab2-content1.html)
#/app/tab2/content2   (tab2-content2.html)
```

The problem is that, it seems like conflict between the tab page. For example, if I first visit `tab1` content page, then I go visit `tab2` content page later on, it will still display `tab1` content. If I visit `tab2` content page first, it will always display `tab2` content no matter how I try to access `tab1` content page.

Why is it like that? Is my structuring wrong? Or, it is ionic bug? How can I overcome it?

edit: Here's my example code for easier understanding:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <!--<script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <!-- MENU Template -->
    <script id="templates/menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/content1">
          Content 1
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/content2">
          Content 2
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/tab/content1">
          Tab 1 Content 1
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/tab/content2">
          Tab 1 Content 2
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/tab2/content1">
          Tab 2 Content 1
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/tab2/content2">
          Tab 2 Content 2
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

    </script>

    <!-- Tab1 Template -->
    <script id="templates/tab1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Tab1 - Content1" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/app/tab/content1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-Content"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Tab1 - Content2" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/app/tab/content2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-Content2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
    </script>

     <!-- Tab2 Template -->
    <script id="templates/tab2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Tab2 - Content1" href="#/app/tab2/content1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab2-Content"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Tab2 - Content2" href="#/app/tab2/content2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab2-Content2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
    </script>

     <!-- Content1 Template -->
    <script id="templates/content1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Content 1">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
    </script>

    <!-- Content2 Template -->
    <script id="templates/content2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Content 2">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    //controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

    .state('app.tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab1.html'
            }
        }
  })
    .state('app.tab2', {
    url: '/tab2',
    views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab2.html'
            }
        }
  })


  .state('app.content1', {
      url: '/content1',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content1.html'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.content2', {
      url: '/content2',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content2.html'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.tab.content1', {
      url: '/content1',
      views: {
        'tab-Content': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content1.html'
        }
      }
    })
 .state('app.tab.content2', {
      url: '/content2',
      views: {
        'tab-Content2': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content2.html'
        }
      }
    })

.state('app.tab2.content1', {
      url: '/content1',
      views: {
        'tab2-Content': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content1.html'
        }
      }
    })
 .state('app.tab2.content2', {
      url: '/content2',
      views: {
        'tab2-Content2': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/content2.html'
        }
      }
    })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/content1');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpVVOr?editors=101

Comment: you need to provide the navigation code for understanding what is going wrong. If possible make a codepen.

Comment: @KaranKumar I have created an example code at codepen for easier understanding the situation. Kindly refer to it. Thanks.

Comment: @KaranKumar If you can't see the problem, please refresh the page when you have test with one of the tab page. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I Think you may have just found a bug. Make a open issue on the github. As far as  I know, your code is correct, I changed the to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tab2/content1');` at the other tabs are showing up. But then first tabs are never rendered. Check this.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNOZBw?editors=101

Comment: @user1995781: Did you try my solution? Did it work? Cheers.

Comment: @LeftyX Yeah, tried with your solution and it works. Thanks a lot for your help. Btw, I also found that adding `abstract: true` to tab url page also avoid the problem.

Comment: @user1995781: Glad I've helped and thanks for the feedback. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of the mysterious ionic navigation. 
I guess nobody has ever mastered this strange beast and, hopefully, at someone, at some point, will be able to fix it ... or, even better, rewrite it.

[Loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186043/how-does-ionic-history-work-and-when-is-a-non-root-stack-created) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364578/ionichistory-backview-has-incorrect-state-when-go-to-previous-state-manually) have been asked on this topic and many more in the forum; issues opened on the subject have been there, pending for ages but there's no definitive answer.

The strange thing is not even the creators have got a proper explanation or are will to answer those questions.

Anyway, going back to your problem. The only way to make it work is to disable the caching system.

**Caching**

> By default, views are cached to improve performance. When a view is
>   navigated away from, its element is left in the DOM, and its scope is
>   disconnected from the $watch cycle. When navigating to a view that is
>   already cached, its scope is then reconnected, and the existing
>   element that was left in the DOM becomes the active view. This also
>   allows for the scroll position of previous views to be maintained.
>
> Caching can be disabled and enabled in multiple ways. By default,
>   Ionic will cache a maximum of 10 views, and not only can this be
>   configured, but apps can also explicitly state which views should and
>   should not be cached.
>
> Note that because we are caching these views, we aren’t destroying
>   scopes. Instead, scopes are being disconnected from the watch cycle.
>   Because scopes are not being destroyed and recreated, controllers are
>   not loading again on a subsequent viewing. If the app/controller needs
>   to know when a view has entered or has left, then view events emitted
>   from the ionView scope, such as $ionicView.enter, may be useful.

Each view is cached - and this is perfectly fine - but when you start messing around with tabs or menus things get out of hand.

If you really want to fix your problem just disable the cache for each state. There are a few options there but the only I've found easy to manage it to set `cache: false` when you're configuring your states:

```
.state('app', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
  })
```

just disable cache for all the states and things will work properly.

This is your working [Plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOdgey?editors=101).

Comment: Interesting answer, I had same experience with $ionicModals. Apparently they are cached in the order they are opened. So when I did some inter opening of modals. (open one modal from other in crazy manners ) the Ionic Modals were opening behind the current modal. Yes Very weird behaviour. The creators should look into it.